# PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, paypal-express

I have a issue in Paypal express checkout Error bellow.
PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

I use two currency base currency is `INR` and payment currency is `USD` and I use Magento 1.7.0.2 version.

Please any one help me.

Comment: How you did base currency is INR and payment currency is USD?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hitting a known bug with 1.7.0.2 tax handling with rounding to the penny. There are many fixes in the wild to fix this, but I would recommend upgrading to 1.8 that fixed the problems I had if you can.

If upgrading isn't an option, there is a extension that should fix the problem: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rounding-error-fix-for-magento-and-paypal.html but I haven't tested this.

There have been a few SO conversations around this too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868985/magento-paypal-tax-rounding-issue

[Does anyone have a fix for PayPal Express NVP Gateway errors due to rounding issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5133/does-anyone-have-a-fix-for-paypal-express-nvp-gateway-errors-due-to-rounding-iss?rq=1)

Comment: product tax class is none.